# remove strong tag for empty spaces in ckeditor

Tags: php, html, ckeditor

How can I remove the strong tag for the empty spaces created after clicking on bold and giving spaces for my text 
for example :
if i  give 10 spaces then it is taking as nbsp space with in strong tag

```
`like_so_&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;` .
```

I want to eliminate that strong tag for my spaces

```
<html>((<strong>  `like_so_&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;`  </strong>)) </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regexp

```
$output = preg_replace('~<strong>((&nbsp;|\s)*)</strong>~', '$1', $input);
```

It'll remove strong tags containing any number of only `&nbsp;` or white characters